# Using right triangle trigonometry, how are values determined?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that angles in a triangle can be determined using inverse trigonometric functions and the SOH CAH TOA mnemonic.  A blind spot for me is how an angle $\theta$, expressed in degrees, is *algebraically* related to the ratio.

For example, if $\theta$ is the $30^\circ$ angle in a 30-60-90 triangle with hypotenuse $4$, adjacent side $2$, and opposite side $2\sqrt{3}$, then
$$ \sin(30^\circ) = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}. $$

I don't see the mathematical use of the degree value $30$ in the trigonometric function, only an intuitive relationship to the ratio.

How do I get degrees from the ratio?   How do I get $30^\circ$ from $1/2$? If I wanted to calculate sine on my own, what would the steps be?  How do I mathematically use the value $30^\circ$ in those steps?

Comment: Suggest a re-check of sides of 30-60-90 triangle. They aren't all rationals as you wrote for H,A,O which I assume mean hypotenuse, adjacent, opposite.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer it.  Nothing shows in the above link how the theta value is applied in the calculation of trigonometric function, only how it is related to a length ratio.

Comment: And log tables don't really address this issue, either, because theta values can be continuous.  For example, sin(30.22212345°) is a valid angle.  So, discrete theta values, as they would be in a table, cannot address continuity.

Comment: The trigonometric functions are transcendental (i.e. they are not algebraic which roughly speaking, means that they cannot be expressed in terms of powers, roots, multiplication/division, and addition/subtraction).  Evaluating transcendental functions at arbitrary points typically requires tools from analysis (limits, Taylor series approximations, Newton's method, etc).  These techniques generally don't give exact answers, but approximations with arbitrary precision.

Comment: I have made significant edits to your question to (in my mind) improve readability and notation.  If you are unhappy with my edits, please revert them.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you so much for your time.  I see I overlooked the use of Taylor Serious in the link provided by David K.  That works for me.

Comment: Xander Henderson, not at all.  Much appreciated.

Comment: As you have indicated that the link David K provided solved your problem, I have closed this question as a duplicate.